# ¿Cómo usar mapear datos de 2 tablas a un DTO usando automapper?

Tags: c#

estoy trabajando un api y en mi capa lógica tengo un perfil de automapper, donde configuro mis tablas con DTOs. El problema que me encontré es que tengo un query en el que saco datos de 2 tablas a través de un join, de momento lo estoy haciendo directamente con un Select pero quiero hacerlo con el mapper que ya tengo configurado para las demás consultas. Así es como lo tengo actualmente:

```
await dbContext.tabla1
                    .Join(
                    dbContext.tabla2,
                    dbTabla1 => dbTabla1.Id,
                    dbTabla2 => dbTabla2.Id,
                    (dbTabla1, dbTabla2) => new { dbTabla1, dbTabla2 }
                    )
                    .Where(x => x.dbTabla1.estado == "ACT")
                    .Select(x => new tablaDTO()
                    {
                        dato1 = x.dbTabla1.campo1,
                        dato2 = x.dbTabla1.campo2,
                        dato3 = x.dbTabla2.campo3,
                        dato4 = x.dbTabla2.campo4,
                    })
                    .ToListAsync();
```

El problema es que por lo que he visto en el mapper no se pueden mapear 2 origenes y un solo destino y no sé si existe alguna otra alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

Crea una class que contenga ambos. Por ejemplo

```
public class TablaGeneral : dbTabla1, dbTabla2
{
}
```

Ya esta clase tiene ambos objetos o en lugar de eso usar asi

```
public class TablaGeneral
{
    public dbTabla1 Tabla1 {get;set;}
    public dbTabla2 Tabla2 {get;set;}
}
```

Entonces al hacer tu consulta mandas el resulta de tus Tablas en esta clase y con este creas tu mapper, igual recuerda los JOIN para que la información se ligue de manera correcta

Comment: De acuerdo, pero el problema es que el createMap del automapper solo recibe un origen no multiples